# How to make diagonal titles on html tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a HTML table with column heads, but each column head has a lengthy title. I would like to make the titles for each column at a diagonal angle. I want to know if there is css (or java, jquery, ect.) to achieve this effect that would work on all browsers (firefox, IE7 &8, ect..) and how to implement it.

Here is a visual example of what I would like to create. [table with diagonal title heads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbw2l.png)

I found this on stackexchange and I couldn't figure out how to put this to good use, or determine if it even applied to what I wanted to do.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14288/how-combine-make-diagonal-column-heads-in-table-with-multicolumn-headers

Comment: Why the heck do you want to support IE6? o.O Check this out for css rotation: http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate

Comment: investigate CSS text rotation

Comment: That question is completely different unfortunately as Tex was made to layout text. Obviously you could always use images to do this, otherwise, take an upvote and lets see if someone is more clever than I.

Comment: @MattK He wants IE6 support, and I think that is going to doom this question to impossible with CSS.

Comment: Use IE filters. It *might* work in IE. `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1.5);`

Comment: @thatidiotguy, I understand. IE since version 4.0 and up (deprecated in 9) has supported Microsoft visual filters and transitions. If you run a quick search on "css text rotation" you'll get a bunch of articles that will give you the full run of browser support for css text rotation, e.g. [http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation)

Comment: @MattK Wow, I stand corrected, there is a way to hack it in to work. Great job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the text you want made diagonal in another element, e.g. a `<div>` and then do a CSS `transform` on that element; see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform#rotate).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   .vertical
    {
    writing-mode:tb-lr;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:block;
    bottom:0;
    width:90px;
    height:120px;   
    position:relative;
    left:90px;
    top:80px;
}
```

see [`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/tNU73/)

[Reference](http://geebart.com/blog/text-rotation-css3)

Comment: yes, simple change to make it 45 degrees gets me the angle I want. Does this CSS work across most browsers?

Comment: how is this a working demo of diagonal table header ? where is the table?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS 3 for modern browsers:

```
-moz-transform:rotate(70deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(70deg);
-o-transform:rotate(70deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(70deg);
transform(70deg);
```

and filter for IE (unfortunately I'm not sure if it's compatible with IE6 and how exactly that works):

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1.5);
```

MSDN source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918(v=vs.85).aspx